# SSIS Catalog Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have SSIS catalog setup on my local machine along with the SQL Server 2014 Database instance. When the package is running via the catalog, the event log gives an error like below:

> The SSIS Execution Process could not write to the IS catalog:
>   (ServerName):SSISDB Error details: Unable to add new messages to the
>   table of operation messages.:Timeout expired. The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding. The statement has been terminated.; at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ISServerHelper.AppendExecutableStatistics(SqlCommand
>   cmd, Int64 operationId, Int64 projectId, Int64 versionId, String
>   packageName, String packageLocationType, String packagePathFull,
>   String executableName, String executableGuid, String packagePath,
>   String executionPath, DateTimeOffset startTime, DateTimeOffset
>   endTime, Int32 executionDuration, Int16 executionResult, Object
>   executionValue) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ExecutableStatistics.WriteInternal(SqlCommand
>   sqlCommand) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.CompositeLog.WriteInternal(SqlCommand
>   sqlCommand) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.Loggable.Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ILoggable.Write(SqlConnection
>   conn)

When the issue happens, it seems that the connection to the SSIS catalog is lost. This happens now and then. I would appreciate if someone can help me through the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after upgrading from 2012 to 2014.  I deleted and re-created the catalog and re-deployed the packages. This solved the issue.